# What am I doing wrong in parsing this regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

My string is:

```
<div> (blah blah blah) ---> quite big HTML before coming to this line.<b>Train No. &amp; Name : </b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;font:12px arial"><span>12672 / SOUTH TRUNK EXP</span></td>
```

I managed to formulate a regular expression

```
var trainDetails = new RegExp("<b>Train No. &amp; Name : </b></td><td.*>([0-9][a-z][A-Z]+)</span></td>", "m");
```

But `trainDetails` are null or are empty.

All I am trying to do is to get the train name and the train number within the span element.

Any pointers where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You have 2 problems in your approach: 1: In regex syntax, the `/` is reserved, and thus needs to be escaped: `\/`. The **Major** issue is that you are trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, which is only very seldom recommended.

Comment: @npinti: Thank you for pointing out as I am a beginner. Can you suggest me a good method to parse HTML with Javascript ?

Comment: @npinti While I agree with parsing _general_ HTML with regex is a bad idea, this is, to be fair, a very specific set of known HTML that is easily parsed with regex.

Comment: The recommended way is to manipulate the DOM of the page through JQuery or Javascript itself so that you dig through the HTML to get to what you are after.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I agree, but I think that this example is simple enough to use the recommended ways, at least, that is my opinion :).

Comment: @npinti Yeah that's true - DOM manipulation would be the easier approach here.  Guess it's down to whether the info above exists in the DOM or it actually is just a string the OP has got from somewhere.

Comment: @Rajesh IMO this is a bad edit - while the code looks nicer, you've introduced newlines into the string being matched, which is a critical feature when dealing with regexes.

Comment: My apologies then. Also I dont think I have rollback permission, so cant even revert it.

Comment: @Rajesh: I have fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks and once again sorry...

Comment: Where does this string actually come from?  Is it actually HTML that's currently rendered in the page, or is it genuinely a separate string?  Either way, the best approach is that taken in @abc's answer - but you need to identify the correct "path" through the HTML to the element containing the data you're interested in.  The difference being, if it's in the current page, you don't need to do the first couple of lines `.createElement` / `.innerHTML = `.  Without seeing the full HTML, identifying a method to get the correct element isn't something we can help with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked for me:

Using RegExp

```
string = '<div> (blah blah blah) ---> quite big HTML before coming to this line.<b>Train No. &amp; Name : </b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;font:12px arial"><span>12672 / SOUTH TRUNK EXP</span></td>';

var trainDetail = string.replace( new RegExp(".*?([^\>]+)(?:\<\/[A-z]+\>)+$","g"), '$1');
```

Using DOM

```
string = ('<b>Train No. &amp; Name : </b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;font:12px arial"><span>12672 / SOUTH TRUNK EXP</span></td>');
string = string.replace(new RegExp( '(<\/?)td', 'g'), '$1xmltd');
tempDoc = document.createElement('xml');
tempDoc.innerHTML = string;
node = tempDoc.getElementsByTagName('xmltd');
trainDetails = node[node.length-1].textContent;
```

Assume condition that last "<td>" in string has train detail.

Comment: I'm trying to execute. Definitely will post if it worked. Thanks for the wonderful answer

Comment: In my use case, there are many characters that precede this html. How to proceed in that case ? (Pls. see the edit)

Comment: sorry cant understand. please explain the cases ?

Comment: My entire string is very big. It is not only the above line. It contains many div, span, etc. Please see my edited question again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99311/discussion-between-vegeta-and-now-he-who-must-not-be-named).

Answer (score 4):

Regular expression is not the ideal solution for this use-case. I suggest using your browser's builtin HTML parser to get the inner HTML of the `<span>`.

```
var el = document.createElement('html');
el.innerHTML = '<div> (blah blah blah) ---> quite big HTML before coming to this line.<b>Train No. &amp; Name : </b></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;font:12px arial"><span>12672 / SOUTH TRUNK EXP</span></td>';
var output = el.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
```

The value of the output variable becomes:

```
12672 / SOUTH TRUNK EXP
```

---

**Edit**

If you are interested in a specific `<span>`, I suggest adding a class to its tag or its parent `<td>` tag, e.g.:

```
<span class="train-number-and-name">
   12672 / SOUTH TRUNK EXP
</span>
```

And fetch it like this:

```
var output = el.querySelector('span.train-number-and-name').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be ok with it : `.+\<span>(.+)\<\/span>.+`
Catch the group #1 and you will get it.

Comment: Here we go, still catch the 1st group : /.+Train No.+\<span\>(.+)\<\/span\>/

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'm slowly starting to understand it.

Comment: I do understand and you are welcome, Debuggex is a great tool, it teached me so much :)